# The truth value of each(Domain set of values for both x and y is the set of real numbers):

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

The truth value of each(Domain set of values for both x and y is the set of real numbers):

a) $\neg(\forall x \exists y \forall z(x+y=z))$

(b)$\forall x(1+2+.....x=\frac{x(x+1)}{2})$

(c) $\forall x(1^2+2^2+.....x^2=\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6})$

(d)$\exists x \forall y(1+2+3...+x=y)$

**my attempt:**

(b) is true

(c) is true

(d) is false

i am confusing with (a) can any one help me with (a) please ..thanks

Comment: Since the domain for $x$ is the set of real numbers, statements (b),(c) are meaningless.

Comment: (d) is just silly.

Comment: @quasi..yes are right but i have dought is (b) and (c) are false

Comment: @quasi..sorry what about (a)

Comment: (a) is true. Suppose the unnegated statement was true. Choose $x$, constant, for example $x=0$. Now what does the unnegated statement say?

Comment: @quasi  ....$y\neq z$

Comment: Well, more precisely, there is no $y$ such $y=z$ for _all_ $z$. Just two distinct values of $z$ would already ruin it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63774/discussion-between-suresh-and-quasi).

Comment: @quasi..can you please explain little more about these four options

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the intended domain is the natural numbers, rather than the real numbers, so let's assume this is about the natiral numbers.

As such, b) and c) are well-known (and thus indeed true) statements about the sum of the first $x$ numbers and the sum of squares of the first $x$ numbers respectively.

And you're also right that d) is false: for whatever $x$ you take, the sum of the first $x$ numbers is a specific number, so it doesn't make sense it would equal all numbers.

Finally, for a), it is easier to first think of the statement without the negation, i.e. $\forall x \exists y \forall z \ (x + y =z)$. That statement has the basically the same problem as d), since whatever the values of $x$ and $y$ are, their sum is of course a *specific* number, and hence is not equal to all numbers. So, without the negation, the statement is false. But that means that with the negation, the statement is true.